# Angular Application not running from docker-compose.yml file

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I have written the below docker file for my angular application .

```
Dockerfile:

# base image
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine AS build-step
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:1.16.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 4100
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Docker images was created successfully.
in docker-compose.yml file I have written:

```
version: '3'
services:
  applicationui:
    image:  applicationui
    build: /
    network_mode: host
    container_name: angular-container
    ports:
      - 4200:4100
```

after executing docker-compose up when I hit the browser with localhost:4200 the page is not opening.

Running docker-compose up
[image]
Any clue where I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overriding Nginx configuration in your Dockerfile, so the actual issue with the port, as Nginx by default listening on `PORT 80`. so change the exposed port.

```
EXPOSE 80
```

As Nginx by default listening on the port `80`, not on port `4100` like Angular ng serve etc that you are expecting from Nginx.

So better to use Expose `80` that will increase readability as @David mentioned don’t have any effect if you set network_mode: host.

So open your browser with `80` and it should work.

or you can bind the desired port without mention the host network in docker-compose

```
    ports:
      - 4200:80
```

http://localhost/

Comment: After changing the docker file port from 4100 to 80  it is now working.In docker compose I also update ports: 80:80

Answer (score 0):

`ports:` don’t have any effect if you set `network_mode: host`.  This setting is frequently thrown in as a workaround for Docker networking issues, and shouldn’t be necessary here.  Just remove that line.  (You can also safely remove `container_name:` and `image:` with no ill effects.)

Comment: I have removed network_mode: host. But still angular app is not up from browser however my angular container is up.